# SVG data image not working as a background-image in a pseudo element

Tags: css, image, firefox, svg

I'm setting a SVG as `background-image` for a pseudo element:

```
content: '';
position: absolute;
 right: 0;
bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
width: 100%;
height: 12px;
background-image: url('data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 620 12" enable-background="new 0 0 620 12" xml:space="preserve"><g><polygon fill="#D11A3C" points="48.8,12 0,12 0,0 54.1,0"/><polygon fill="#952592" points="93.8,12 44,12 49.3,0 99.1,0"/><polygon fill="#1E65AF" points="133.5,12 83.7,12 89,0 138.8,0"/><polygon fill="#D11A3C" points="156.3,12 106.5,12 111.8,0 161.6,0"/><polygon fill="#40BFC2" points="201,12 151.3,12 156.5,0 206.3,0"/><polygon fill="#1E65AF" points="216.4,12 166.6,12 171.9,0 221.7,0"/><polygon fill="#952592" points="226.5,12 176.7,12 182,0 231.7,0"/><polygon fill="#1E65AF" points="241.3,12 191.5,12 196.8,0 246.6,0"/><polygon fill="#40BFC2" points="260.9,12 211.1,12 216.4,0 266.2,0"/><polygon fill="#952592" points="282.6,12 232.9,12 238.1,0 287.9,0"/><polygon fill="#952592" points="282.6,12 232.9,12 238.1,0 287.9,0"/><polygon fill="#D11A3C" points="318.6,12 268.9,12 274.2,0 323.9,0"/><polygon fill="#D11A3C" points="318.6,12 268.9,12 274.2,0 323.9,0"/><polygon fill="#40BFC2" points="364.2,12 314.4,12 319.7,0 369.5,0"/><polygon fill="#1E65AF" points="368.1,12 318.3,12 323.6,0 373.4,0"/><polygon fill="#1E65AF" points="368.1,12 318.3,12 323.6,0 373.4,0"/><polygon fill="#D11A3C" points="378.5,12 328.7,12 334,0 383.8,0"/><polygon fill="#D11A3C" points="378.5,12 328.7,12 334,0 383.8,0"/><polygon fill="#40BFC2" points="424.8,12 375,12 380.3,0 430.1,0"/><polygon fill="#40BFC2" points="424.8,12 375,12 380.3,0 430.1,0"/><polygon fill="#952592" points="430.1,12 380.3,12 385.6,0 435.4,0"/><polygon fill="#1E65AF" points="465.6,12 415.8,12 421.1,0 470.9,0"/><polygon fill="#D11A3C" points="488.3,12 438.5,12 443.8,0 493.6,0"/><polygon fill="#D11A3C" points="620,12 613.4,12 618.7,0 620,0"/><polygon fill="#40BFC2" points="534.2,12 484.5,12 489.8,0 539.5,0"/><polygon fill="#1E65AF" points="548,12 498.2,12 503.5,0 553.3,0"/><polygon fill="#952592" points="556.5,12 506.7,12 512,0 561.8,0"/><polygon fill="#1E65AF" points="573.8,12 524.1,12 529.4,0 579.1,0"/><polygon fill="#40BFC2" points="592.5,12 542.8,12 548.1,0 597.8,0"/><polygon fill="#952592" points="614.4,12 564.6,12 569.9,0 619.7,0"/></g></svg>');
background-repeat: repeat-x;
background-position: bottom;
```

but for some reason it does not show up on Firefox. I do not wanna use a base64 data-url. Isn't this possible at all in Firefox?

Comment: @Paulie_D height is working fine, this is a Foundation Sass function. The output is 12px in rem unit. I edited to not cause confusion

Comment: I like to base64 encode my svg and png if I ever inline them in my CSS as a background image.

Comment: @hungerstar https://css-tricks.com/probably-dont-base64-svg/

Comment: Did not know that, thanks for the link. Personally I only base64 encode on small basic shapes like the icons you would find in a icon font.

Comment: FWIW - this is also a problem when setting data in an `<img src="...">` attribute. Same solution applies.

Answer (score 160, accepted):

The # character in a URL is reserved to indicate the start of a [fragment identifier](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fragment_identifier).

You must URL encode the data URL contents, which means converting any hash characters in the data URL to %23

Comment: @Robert Longson, do you know why this is specific to Firefox and IE Edge and Chrome related browsers don't bother with this fragment identifier rule? Or are they just being kind?

Comment: @PeterS IE Edge and Chrome have bugs in this regard.

Comment: My data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg... images just broke after working for years. Apparently Chrome is now paying attention to the special meaning of #. Thanks for the help!

Comment: You can use [this tool](https://yoksel.github.io/url-encoder/) to encode the SVG, it's by the maker of SVGOMG (svg optimization using svgo)

Answer (score 13):

You can use the `encodeURIComponent(uri)` function of JS.

This function encodes special characters and can encodes also the following characters: `, / ? : @ & = + $ #`

Reference: *https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_encodeuricomponent.asp*

Comment: ``%<>[\]^`{|}#$&+, /:;=?`` <-- this is the full set of ASCII characters that encodeURIComponent escapes. It includes spaces.

Answer (score 5):

For anyone having this encoding issue when trying to use url with sass variables (for fills, for instance), the following is quite useful: 
https://gist.github.com/JacobDB/0ffffaf8e772c12acf7102edb8a302be

Note, you may need to edit the output url from inline-svg depending on your needs (in my case, I was using `data:image/svg+xml;utf8` instead)

Answer (score 2):

A related question " svg fill color not working with hex colors"
[svg fill color not working with hex colors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61099149/svg-fill-color-not-working-with-hex-colors)
was referred here.
The example given was:

OK:  <path fill='red' ...
Not OK:  <path fill='#FF0000' ...

I encountered a similar problem trying to export an svg using XMLSerializer.
The exported svg was truncated following the # character.
In my case, the %23 substitution for # did not work.

I was able to work around the problem by replacing the hex constant with the rgb() function and decimal values. For example, fill ="#FF0000" becomes
fill = "rgb(255,0,0)"

Comment: Thanks for sharing, took me a while to figure out the Hex color issue