# close icon using SVG is not displaying

Tags: html, css, svg

i'm trying to display close icon using svg but it is not showing anything
could anyone help me how to get this. this looks simple but I didn't understand why it is not working

SCSS:

```
.close {
    background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' width='53.7' height='53.7' viewBox='0 0 53.7 53.7'><path opacity='.6' fill='#666E6E' d='M35.6 34.4L28 26.8l7.6-7.6c.2-.2.2-.5 0-.7l-.5-.5c-.2-.2-.5-.2-.7 0l-7.6 7.6-7.5-7.6c-.2-.2-.5-.2-.7 0l-.6.6c-.2.2-.2.5 0 .7l7.6 7.6-7.6 7.5c-.2.2-.2.5 0 .7l.5.5c.2.2.5.2.7 0l7.6-7.6 7.6 7.6c.2.2.5.2.7 0l.5-.5c.2-.2.2-.5 0-.7z'/></svg>");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: contain;
    position: absolute;
    cursor: pointer;
    padding-left: 5px;
  }
```

html

```
  <div class='close'></div>
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to define a width and height.

UPDATE:

The fill property of the svg contains a hash symbol `#` which needs to be replaced by `%23` in order for it to work.

More details here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/30733736/4305494

---

**Code Snippet:**

```css
.close {
  background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' width='53.7' height='53.7' viewBox='0 0 53.7 53.7'><path opacity='.6' fill='%23666E6E' d='M35.6 34.4L28 26.8l7.6-7.6c.2-.2.2-.5 0-.7l-.5-.5c-.2-.2-.5-.2-.7 0l-7.6 7.6-7.5-7.6c-.2-.2-.5-.2-.7 0l-.6.6c-.2.2-.2.5 0 .7l7.6 7.6-7.6 7.5c-.2.2-.2.5 0 .7l.5.5c.2.2.5.2.7 0l7.6-7.6 7.6 7.6c.2.2.5.2.7 0l.5-.5c.2-.2.2-.5 0-.7z'/></svg>");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: contain;
  position: absolute;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding-left: 5px;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div class='close'></div>
```

---

How about using the SVG `<symbol>` tag instead? You will be writting semantic HTML and you can use it wherever you want as well, with the `<use>` tag.

---

Here's a simple demo on how to achieve this.

```css
.icon {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 1em;
  height: 1em;
  stroke-width: 0;
  stroke: currentColor;
  fill: currentColor;
}

.icon-close {
  font-size: 3rem;
  color: #666E6E;
  opacity: 0.6;
}
```

```html
<a href="#">
  <svg class="icon icon-close">
    <use xlink:href="#icon-close"></use>
  </svg>
</a>

<svg style="display:none;">
  <symbol id="icon-close" viewBox="0 0 53.7 53.7">
    <title>Close icon</title>
    <path d='M35.6 34.4L28 26.8l7.6-7.6c.2-.2.2-.5 0-.7l-.5-.5c-.2-.2-.5-.2-.7 0l-7.6 7.6-7.5-7.6c-.2-.2-.5-.2-.7 0l-.6.6c-.2.2-.2.5 0 .7l7.6 7.6-7.6 7.5c-.2.2-.2.5 0 .7l.5.5c.2.2.5.2.7 0l7.6-7.6 7.6 7.6c.2.2.5.2.7 0l.5-.5c.2-.2.2-.5 0-.7z' />
  </symbol>
</svg>
```

Comment: Nope it is not working

Comment: Could you provide a demo where the problem can be reproduced?

Comment: Also, make sure the parent of the div with class close has the CSS property `position: relative;`

Comment: oh I see 
icon is there but it is incredibly small!

Comment: Note that you also need to encode special characters (such as `#` in FF and others in different versions of IE, safest is to pass all your markup through `encodeURIComponent()`). Currently, the snippet doesn't work in FF because of that.