# svg fill color not working with hex colors

Tags: css, svg, background

Trying to create an svg background pattern, but:

When I am not using fill it is ok, when using color name like: `color: red;` it's ok, but if using hex colors, nothing shows up.

here are the codes:

OK:

```
background: url("data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' width='20' height='10' ><path fill='red' d='M 0,10 H 20 L 10,0 Z' /></svg>")  repeat-x;
```

NOT OK:

```
background: url("data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' width='20' height='10' ><path fill='#FF0000' d='M 0,10 H 20 L 10,0 Z' /></svg>")  repeat-x;
```

also check out on jsfiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/vajnabotond/r362xdjn/19/

Answer (score 204, accepted):

`#` in URLs starts a fragment identifier. So, in order to make that work, write `%23` instead of `#`. That is the value of escaped `#` character.

```
background: url("data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' width='20' height='10' ><path fill='%23FF0000' d='M 0,10 H 20 L 10,0 Z' /></svg>")  repeat-x;
```

You can find it all well explained on following link: https://codepen.io/gunnarbittersmann/pen/BoovjR

Comment: Is `#` the **only** character to be escaped ?

Comment: My bad, I was using the API wrong. I'd suggest using `encodeURIComponent` if the SVG is created at runtime from a string.