# Scale an SVG responsively in CSS

Tags: html, css, svg

I'm wondering how to scale an SVG to look nice on every screen size. Here's what I have

- A linear gradient as background
- 2 masks that I need to apply on top of it, with white space on top of the top one and at the bottom of the bottom one

I managed to reproduce the design that I want at a size of 320x770 pixels, but I'm pulling my hair out to find how I coud make it scale well for different screen sizes or orientations.

I've created  a code sandbox to showcase my problem (open it to a new window of 320x770 to see the desired result). https://codesandbox.io/s/blissful-frost-ste6y?file=/pages/index.vue

```css
main section {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.wave-wrapper {
  background: linear-gradient(#0e548c, #197d89, #0e548c);
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.above-waves {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
}

.white {
  margin-top: 160px;
  color: #fff;
}

.mask-1,
.mask-2 {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  width: 100%;
}

.mask-1__image {
  width: 100%;
  transform: translateY(-53%);
}

.mask-2__image {
  width: 100%;
  transform: translateY(-55%);
}
```

```html
<main>
    <section>Section A</section>
    <div class="wave-wrapper">
      <div class="mask-1">
        <img class="mask-1__image" src="https://ste6y.sse.codesandbox.io/_nuxt/assets/waves-mask-1.svg" alt="Waves mask 1">
      </div>
      <div class="above-waves">
        <section>Section B</section>
        <section>Section C</section>
      </div>
      <div class="mask-2">
        <img class="mask-2__image" src="data:image/svg+xml;base64,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" alt="Waves mask 2">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div>
      <section>Section D</section>
    </div>
  </main>
```

Here's what I've tried so far:

- Scale the SVG relative to the parent by at some point it just becomes way too big
- Keep the original size but I end up with the gradient showing on the sides

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would first simplify your code to consider multiple background then I edited your SVG a little and added `preserveAspectRatio="none"` to allow them to scale:

```css
main section {
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.wave-wrapper {
  background: 
   url('data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" preserveAspectRatio="none"  viewBox="0 0 320 320"><g transform="translate(0.234 -830)"><path  d="M-1145,64.915V329.746s22.005-19.129,79.3-16.761,56.2-27.834,73.869-65.12a638.771,638.771,0,0,0,27.089-65.789s-7.336-47.7,40-38.816,99.508-78.345,99.508-78.345V-742.778H-1145Z" transform="translate(1145 762)" fill="%23fff"/><path  d="M-1145,1093.2s-4.7-4.83,28.093-16.427c17.284-6.111,50.688,2.344,71.642-5.336,2.49-.912,20.226-6.871,29.843-19.3,5.073-6.558,14.5-24.414,26.67-49.892a460.544,460.544,0,0,0,19.872-49.015s1.287-31.084,11.2-41.9,29.93-7.273,29.93-7.273,14.885.669,27.688-3.488,25.246-15.641,43.839-33.959a210.939,210.939,0,0,0,30.76-39.311s-17.815,35.666-39.747,59.618-37.356,33.452-48.208,36.191-22.293-.251-30.053,5.818-13.259,15.752-14.209,32.117c-.669,11.521-21.459,52.772-39.6,84-11.908,17.052-29.306,34.514-35.62,36.561-21.333,6.915-44.562,5.125-44.562,5.125s-30.163-1.633-47.047,15.7-20.49,53.617-20.49,53.617Z" transform="translate(1145)" fill="%2393b5c5"/></g></svg>') 
   top / 101% 40%,
   url('data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" preserveAspectRatio="none"  viewBox="0 0 320 330"><g  transform="translate(0.475 -1760)"><path  d="M-1145,2154.757V979.06s3.991,25.572,26.369,53.919,33.812,41.355,63.142,59.468c17.212,10.629,32.987,17.935,47.575,25.332,49.62,25.161,86.942,33.76,86.942,33.76s52.454,7.444,95.5,72.175v931.042Z" transform="translate(1145 864)" fill="%23fff"/><path  d="M-1145,855s-9.684,98.587,58.447,173.838c39.516,43.645,118.16,87.019,160.446,105.172,30.4,13.049,34.891,11.235,62.2,31.748,27.331,23.911,38.43,58.447,38.43,58.447s-28.61-39.481-64.1-58.447c-13.983-7.473-44.519-16.914-69.277-26.376-37.377-14.285-76.232-30.6-110.643-55.781-56.784-41.555-75.506-99.531-75.506-99.531Z" transform="translate(1145 864)" fill="%2393b5c5"/></g></svg>')
   bottom / 101% 40%,
   linear-gradient(#0e548c, #197d89, #0e548c);
 background-repeat:no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<main>
  <section>Section A</section>
  <div class="wave-wrapper">
    <section>Section B</section>
    <section>Section C</section>
  </div>
  <section>Section D</section>
</main>
```

You can easily switch the position:

```css
main section {
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.wave-wrapper {
  background: 
   url('data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" preserveAspectRatio="none"  viewBox="0 0 320 320"><g transform="translate(0.234 -830)"><path  d="M-1145,64.915V329.746s22.005-19.129,79.3-16.761,56.2-27.834,73.869-65.12a638.771,638.771,0,0,0,27.089-65.789s-7.336-47.7,40-38.816,99.508-78.345,99.508-78.345V-742.778H-1145Z" transform="translate(1145 762)" fill="%23fff"/><path  d="M-1145,1093.2s-4.7-4.83,28.093-16.427c17.284-6.111,50.688,2.344,71.642-5.336,2.49-.912,20.226-6.871,29.843-19.3,5.073-6.558,14.5-24.414,26.67-49.892a460.544,460.544,0,0,0,19.872-49.015s1.287-31.084,11.2-41.9,29.93-7.273,29.93-7.273,14.885.669,27.688-3.488,25.246-15.641,43.839-33.959a210.939,210.939,0,0,0,30.76-39.311s-17.815,35.666-39.747,59.618-37.356,33.452-48.208,36.191-22.293-.251-30.053,5.818-13.259,15.752-14.209,32.117c-.669,11.521-21.459,52.772-39.6,84-11.908,17.052-29.306,34.514-35.62,36.561-21.333,6.915-44.562,5.125-44.562,5.125s-30.163-1.633-47.047,15.7-20.49,53.617-20.49,53.617Z" transform="translate(1145)" fill="%2393b5c5"/></g></svg>') 
   bottom / 101% 50%,
   url('data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" preserveAspectRatio="none"  viewBox="0 0 320 330"><g  transform="translate(0.475 -1760)"><path  d="M-1145,2154.757V979.06s3.991,25.572,26.369,53.919,33.812,41.355,63.142,59.468c17.212,10.629,32.987,17.935,47.575,25.332,49.62,25.161,86.942,33.76,86.942,33.76s52.454,7.444,95.5,72.175v931.042Z" transform="translate(1145 864)" fill="%23fff"/><path  d="M-1145,855s-9.684,98.587,58.447,173.838c39.516,43.645,118.16,87.019,160.446,105.172,30.4,13.049,34.891,11.235,62.2,31.748,27.331,23.911,38.43,58.447,38.43,58.447s-28.61-39.481-64.1-58.447c-13.983-7.473-44.519-16.914-69.277-26.376-37.377-14.285-76.232-30.6-110.643-55.781-56.784-41.555-75.506-99.531-75.506-99.531Z" transform="translate(1145 864)" fill="%2393b5c5"/></g></svg>')
   top / 101% 50%,
   linear-gradient(#0e548c, #197d89, #0e548c);
 background-repeat:no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<main>
  <section>Section A</section>
  <div class="wave-wrapper">
    <section>Section B</section>
    <section>Section C</section>
  </div>
  <section>Section D</section>
</main>
```

---

Like below for each section:

```css
main section {
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

section:nth-child(2) {
  background:
   url('data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" preserveAspectRatio="none"  viewBox="0 0 320 320"><g transform="translate(0.234 -830)"><path  d="M-1145,64.915V329.746s22.005-19.129,79.3-16.761,56.2-27.834,73.869-65.12a638.771,638.771,0,0,0,27.089-65.789s-7.336-47.7,40-38.816,99.508-78.345,99.508-78.345V-742.778H-1145Z" transform="translate(1145 762)" fill="%23fff"/><path  d="M-1145,1093.2s-4.7-4.83,28.093-16.427c17.284-6.111,50.688,2.344,71.642-5.336,2.49-.912,20.226-6.871,29.843-19.3,5.073-6.558,14.5-24.414,26.67-49.892a460.544,460.544,0,0,0,19.872-49.015s1.287-31.084,11.2-41.9,29.93-7.273,29.93-7.273,14.885.669,27.688-3.488,25.246-15.641,43.839-33.959a210.939,210.939,0,0,0,30.76-39.311s-17.815,35.666-39.747,59.618-37.356,33.452-48.208,36.191-22.293-.251-30.053,5.818-13.259,15.752-14.209,32.117c-.669,11.521-21.459,52.772-39.6,84-11.908,17.052-29.306,34.514-35.62,36.561-21.333,6.915-44.562,5.125-44.562,5.125s-30.163-1.633-47.047,15.7-20.49,53.617-20.49,53.617Z" transform="translate(1145)" fill="%2393b5c5"/></g></svg>')
   top right/101% 80% no-repeat, 
   linear-gradient(#0e548c, #197d89);
}

section:nth-child(3) {
  background: 
   url('data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" preserveAspectRatio="none"  viewBox="0 0 320 330"><g  transform="translate(0.475 -1760)"><path  d="M-1145,2154.757V979.06s3.991,25.572,26.369,53.919,33.812,41.355,63.142,59.468c17.212,10.629,32.987,17.935,47.575,25.332,49.62,25.161,86.942,33.76,86.942,33.76s52.454,7.444,95.5,72.175v931.042Z" transform="translate(1145 864)" fill="%23fff"/><path  d="M-1145,855s-9.684,98.587,58.447,173.838c39.516,43.645,118.16,87.019,160.446,105.172,30.4,13.049,34.891,11.235,62.2,31.748,27.331,23.911,38.43,58.447,38.43,58.447s-28.61-39.481-64.1-58.447c-13.983-7.473-44.519-16.914-69.277-26.376-37.377-14.285-76.232-30.6-110.643-55.781-56.784-41.555-75.506-99.531-75.506-99.531Z" transform="translate(1145 864)" fill="%2393b5c5"/></g></svg>')
   bottom right/101% 80% no-repeat, 
   linear-gradient(#197d89, #0e548c);
}
```

```html
<main>
  <section>Section A</section>
  <section>Section B</section>
  <section>Section C</section>
  <section>Section D</section>
</main>
```

As a bonus you can also consider mask to have transparency instead of white color:

```css
:root {
  --svg1:url('data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" preserveAspectRatio="none"  viewBox="0 0 320 320"><g transform="translate(0.234 -830)"><path  d="M-1145,64.915V329.746s22.005-19.129,79.3-16.761,56.2-27.834,73.869-65.12a638.771,638.771,0,0,0,27.089-65.789s-7.336-47.7,40-38.816,99.508-78.345,99.508-78.345V-742.778H-1145Z" transform="translate(1145 762)" fill="%23fff"/><path  d="M-1145,1093.2s-4.7-4.83,28.093-16.427c17.284-6.111,50.688,2.344,71.642-5.336,2.49-.912,20.226-6.871,29.843-19.3,5.073-6.558,14.5-24.414,26.67-49.892a460.544,460.544,0,0,0,19.872-49.015s1.287-31.084,11.2-41.9,29.93-7.273,29.93-7.273,14.885.669,27.688-3.488,25.246-15.641,43.839-33.959a210.939,210.939,0,0,0,30.76-39.311s-17.815,35.666-39.747,59.618-37.356,33.452-48.208,36.191-22.293-.251-30.053,5.818-13.259,15.752-14.209,32.117c-.669,11.521-21.459,52.772-39.6,84-11.908,17.052-29.306,34.514-35.62,36.561-21.333,6.915-44.562,5.125-44.562,5.125s-30.163-1.633-47.047,15.7-20.49,53.617-20.49,53.617Z" transform="translate(1145)" fill="%2393b5c5"/></g></svg>');
  --svg1-mask:url('data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" preserveAspectRatio="none"  viewBox="0 0 320 320"><g transform="translate(0.234 -830)"><path  d="M-1145,64.915V329.746s22.005-19.129,79.3-16.761,56.2-27.834,73.869-65.12a638.771,638.771,0,0,0,27.089-65.789s-7.336-47.7,40-38.816,99.508-78.345,99.508-78.345V-742.778H-1145Z" transform="translate(1145 762)" fill="%23fff"/></g></svg>');
  --svg2:url('data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" preserveAspectRatio="none"  viewBox="0 0 320 330"><g  transform="translate(0.475 -1760)"><path  d="M-1145,2154.757V979.06s3.991,25.572,26.369,53.919,33.812,41.355,63.142,59.468c17.212,10.629,32.987,17.935,47.575,25.332,49.62,25.161,86.942,33.76,86.942,33.76s52.454,7.444,95.5,72.175v931.042Z" transform="translate(1145 864)" fill="%23fff"/><path  d="M-1145,855s-9.684,98.587,58.447,173.838c39.516,43.645,118.16,87.019,160.446,105.172,30.4,13.049,34.891,11.235,62.2,31.748,27.331,23.911,38.43,58.447,38.43,58.447s-28.61-39.481-64.1-58.447c-13.983-7.473-44.519-16.914-69.277-26.376-37.377-14.285-76.232-30.6-110.643-55.781-56.784-41.555-75.506-99.531-75.506-99.531Z" transform="translate(1145 864)" fill="%2393b5c5"/></g></svg>');
  --svg2-mask:url('data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" preserveAspectRatio="none"  viewBox="0 0 320 330"><g  transform="translate(0.475 -1760)"><path  d="M-1145,2154.757V979.06s3.991,25.572,26.369,53.919,33.812,41.355,63.142,59.468c17.212,10.629,32.987,17.935,47.575,25.332,49.62,25.161,86.942,33.76,86.942,33.76s52.454,7.444,95.5,72.175v931.042Z" transform="translate(1145 864)" fill="%23fff"/></g></svg>');
}

main section {
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  position:relative;
  z-index:0;
}

section:nth-child(2):before,
section:nth-child(3):before{
  content:"";
  position:absolute;
  z-index:-1;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  right:0;
  bottom:0;
  
  --s:101% 80%; /* control the height(80%) to adjust the SVG */
  /* Mask */
  -webkit-mask:
     var(--m),
     linear-gradient(#fff,#fff);
          mask:
     var(--m),
     linear-gradient(#fff,#fff);
  -webkit-mask-size: var(--s),100% 100%;
          mask-size: var(--s),100% 100%;
  -webkit-mask-position:var(--p);
          mask-position:var(--p);
  -webkit-mask-composite:destination-out;
          mask-composite:exclude;
  -webkit-mask-repeat:no-repeat;
          mask-repeat:no-repeat;
  /* background */
  background:
     var(--b) var(--p)/var(--s), 
     linear-gradient(var(--d),#0e548c, #197d89);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

section:nth-child(2) {
  --m:var(--svg1-mask);
  --p:top right;
  --b:var(--svg1);
  --d:180deg;
}

section:nth-child(3) {
  --m:var(--svg2-mask);
  --p:bottom right;
  --b:var(--svg2);
  --d:0deg;
}

body {
  background:grey;
  margin:0;
}
```

```html
<main>
  <section>Section A</section>
  <section>Section B</section>
  <section>Section C</section>
  <section>Section D</section>
</main>
```

Comment: Your svg seems to scale very nicely, could you please sum up what you changed inside it ? The color is fully black instead of white for me

Comment: @ThéoLavaux I removed width/height from it, adjust the viewbox to make it almost square then adjust the translation of the element inside so they fit inside the new viewbox I defined. Your SVG contain a lot of non-needed space so I tried to reduce it. Here is the SVG alone: https://jsfiddle.net/dkqrwsax/

Comment: @ThéoLavaux and more important, you need to convert # to %23 when using it inside background or mask

Comment: The blank space was a first attempt to make up for white empty space

Comment: What do you mean with the conversion ?

Comment: @ThéoLavaux check this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/30733736/8620333

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/214989/discussion-between-theo-lavaux-and-temani-afif).

Comment: @ThéoLavaux update the answer to show how you can control the height of SVG isntead of having 100% height